# What Gitlab tool used for code coverage reports?

Tags: kotlin, gitlab, gitlab-ci, test-coverage

Instead of using JaCoCo, I was told, that there would be an internal Gitlab tool, where I can create test coverage reports?

- I do not want to use JaCoCo.
- I am not interessted in any vizualization plugin within Gitlab.
- I would like to generate a xml/html file(s) with e.g. bar graphs, what can be emailed and opened externally.

I couldn't find anything in the Gitlab dashboard menu. The project is a Android App Kotlin project.

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html#java-and-kotlin-examples) what your are looking for ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I wrote "instead" to get rid of JaCoCo. I was looking for a solution **without** JaCoCo. The linked examples are depending on JaCoCo

Comment: Well these are just examples of configuration. Just adapt to use the tools you like. I am not aware of gitlab providing those tools out of the box. To my knowledge it only focuses on report visualization as is explained in the already linked documentation and preceding/following chapters.

Answer (score 5):

the question is what part of Coverage you want to see/have:

- just a number within the MR - therefore GitLab parses the logoutput of the Jobs
- coverage visualization within MR - therefore you need to provide a report.

### Coverage in Overview

For the coverage in the Overview and just to get a percentage, you need to configure your job with an regex how it can be parsed like

```yaml
job1:
  # ....
  coverage: '/Code coverage: \d+\.\d+/'
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#coverage

### Visualization

We are actually using JaCoCo, but to make the coverage visible and to have the information in Merge Requests you have to convert everything into Cobertura Reports.

There are different approaches to achieve this:

1. with a gradle-plugin like https://github.com/kageiit/gradle-jacobo-plugin

   the configuration is pretty neat, and if you do have already a gradle build it is easy to integrate
2. with an own step within the CI Pipeline - see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html

   ```yaml
   test-jdk11:
      stage: test
      image: gradle:6.6.1-jdk11
      script:
        - 'gradle test jacocoTestReport' # jacoco must be configured to create an xml report
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - build/jacoco/jacoco.xml

    coverage-jdk11:
      # Must be in a stage later than test-jdk11's stage.
      # The `visualize` stage does not exist by default.
      # Please define it first, or chose an existing stage like `deploy`.
      stage: visualize
      image: registry.gitlab.com/haynes/jacoco2cobertura:1.0.7
      script:
        # convert report from jacoco to cobertura, using relative project path
        - python /opt/cover2cover.py build/jacoco/jacoco.xml $CI_PROJECT_DIR/src/main/java/ > build/cobertura.xml
      needs: ["test-jdk11"]
      artifacts:
        reports:
          cobertura: build/cobertura.xml
   ```

important to note is that you always will have to tell GitLab CI your path to the artifact for cobertura with

```yaml
job:
    #...
    artifacts:
      reports:
        cobertura: build/cobertura.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Our approach is the following.
have to tell Gitlab where your coverage report is, for example we have this setup for a java unit test report **"jacoco.xml"**:

```
 Unit Test:
      stage: pruebas 
      script:
        - echo "Iniciar Pruebas"
        - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
      artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
          junit: 
            - target/surefire-reports/*Test.xml
            - target/failsafe-reports/*Test.xml
          cobertura: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
```

Our summary in Gitlab :
[image]

Unit Test Detaills:
[image]

The key is your **"jacoco.xml"**.

Comment: just to clarify the overview of unittests within the pipeline, has nothing to do with your `jacoco.xml` - this is just the rendering of your junit reports :)

Comment: @simon how does it have nothing to do with it?
If you don't indicate where your coverage file is, gitlab can't show it, magically they won't show, you have to indicate where your report  "jacoco.xml" file is. if you do not indicat it, the report shows 0.

Comment: Actually you should take a close look at your build. First jacoco.xml is not compatible with cobertura coverage information. If it is in cobertura format, you should rename that file ;) - second the unit test overview, based on the assumption that you are feeding a Jacob report into cobertura, rewults that your test overview is based on the junit reports, provided via the report annotation. Your answer with "the key is the Jacoco.xml" is therefore misleading, and can misguide people. As it can not be a Jacoco report

Comment: You will get the same result with the tests, if you remove the cobertura part out of your yaml file

Comment: believe me that when I did not have that configuration my reports are not shown, but I will try to remove them and try. good contribution

Comment: See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html for unit test reports